# How to efficiently solve a quadratic program repeatedly?

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have a quadratic problem, 
\begin{align}
\min_{x\in [0,1]^n} x^T p+ \frac{1}{2\lambda} x^T Q x
\end{align}
($Q$ is semidefinite)
which I want to solve repeatedly, with the slight change of p and Q, in each iteration. $n$ length of the vector $x$ is at most 1000.

I need a method as fast as possible, which I can use the result of previous solve of the problem. How to solve this problem which uses the result of previous iteration as starting point( may be warm-starting in next iteration)
This question already posted on computational science.

Comment: active set methods are probably more suitable for bootstrap with the last optimal solution. interior points methods usually do not benefit from bootstrapping.

Comment: Just to be perfectly precise, $x$ is not a discrete variable but rather a continuous variable in the unit-hypersphere?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas, yes, $x$ is a continous variable.

Comment: @user251257, do you know of any implemented version, which is stable and efficient and I can test on the data? Otherwise, is there any accelerated version of it that I can implement?are the active set methods the most efficient among other alternatives?

Comment: @user85361 do you have matlab? It has an active method. I'm not sure about interior point for convex QP